# Получение переменной int в static методе (Java/Android Studio)

Tags: java, методы

Необходимо изменить  переменную на число 3:

```
 private int step = 1;
```

С помощью static метода:

```
    public static void  onDoubleTap() {

//-----Получить переменную и изменить её-----

           System.out.println("Переменная изменена на число 3");
        }
```

Переменную статичной делать не надо!

Comment: Это можно сделать, только передав экземпляр класса в метод. Без этого у статического метода не будет доступа к переменной экземпляра. Ну или саму переменную сделать статической. И она у вас явно не локальная, но поле класса

Comment: Юрий, можно подробнее, как перенести?

Comment: Ну... Типа как-то так: `public static void  onDoubleTap(ClassName instance) { instance.step+=3; }` потом вызывать надо будет так: `ClassName.onDoubleTap(classNameInstance)`. Но мне кажется, что вы пытаетесь решить неизвестную нам задачу каким-то неправильным способом.

Comment: Спасибо за объяснение, Юрий, буду пробовать.

Comment: вы явно пытаетесь решить проблему с помощью костыля. Лучше всего вам описать саму решаемую задачу, чтобы получить правильное решение, а не ваше неправльное представление о ее решении. В андроид в общем случае не должно быть никаких статических методов.